# Why the data size change after a process with Hadoop?

Tags: apache, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, bigdata

For example when i run a word-count the input size is different from the output.Is that just because of the counter or is something else?

Is there any way to predict the size of the output, depending on the code that i am using.
Can anyone explain that to me or suggest me anything useful to read..

Answer (score 1):

I believe it all depends on the transformation you are doing in reducer .

Let's take the word count example , if you have a bigger file of size 1GB , when you do the word count ,the reducer output will be distinct words in the file with their occurrence.

In this case , it is obvious that , your output file size is going to shrink .

If you take a another example , where you just write it back to output file with out any transformation , in this case , your reducer output size should match with your mapper input size.

I hope it make sense , it all depends on the logic you have in your reducer.